# Stuck at a blank screen after nvidia update

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I have tried everything. Looked into every single thread, nothing is working.

I tried pressing <kbd>e</kbd> in GRUB and adding "nomodeset"

I tried "nouveau.modeset=0"

Recovery mode doesn't help because when I open the root shell, the files are read-only.

I can't boot into tty

The screen is blank, nothing is responsive.

Answer (score 1):

1. Escape from black screen

   When you stuck on black screen, you can use Ctrl+Alt+F1 to select tty. Then you can type your username and password to login.
2. edit `/etc/default/grub`

   Modify the line of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT='pcie_port_pm=off acpi_backlight=none acpi_osi=Linux acpi_osi=! acpi_osi="Windows 2009"'
   ```

   Then reboot again. You should be able to see login page.
3. Re-install nvidia driver (If step 1 & 2 cannot help)

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-390 nvidia-settings
   ```